Lock-free thread safe lazy manual initialization of singleton in modern C++
I know Singleton is not good and that in general the thread safe lazy initialization in modern C++ can be done by static local variable, but I have quite specific use case and although I can use safer "less-performant" techniques(double check with mutex for the second check), I still would love to verify my understandings on atomic variables and memory ordering.
Also the main reason I cannot use static local variable is because it needs to be shared between DLL/SO boundaries. - Please ignore that statement and just accept that I want to do the initialization myself.
This is the code which came to my mind as the most performant lock-free solution without using stronger memory barriers.
It seems to work, but I do wonder if that is really the case.
Is my usage of memory ordering correct here? Will it have the expected behavior?
// in header file
class DLL_EXPORT MyLogger
{
public:
    void logMessage(std::string message);

private:
    static std::atomic<MyLogger*> sSharedInstance;
}

// in cpp file
constinit std::atomic<MyLogger*> MyLogger::sSharedInstance{nullptr};

MyLogger& MyLogger::sharedInstance()
{
    MyLogger* logger = sSharedInstance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    if (!logger)
    {
        logger = new MyLogger(); // The constructor is no-op, so redundant instances are not an issue.
        MyLogger* previousLogger = nullptr;
        if (!sSharedInstance.compare_exchange_strong(previousLogger, logger, std::memory_order_relaxed, std::memory_order_relaxed))
        {
            // Lost the init race - destroy the redundant logger
            delete logger;
            logger = previousLogger;
        }
    }

    return *logger;
}

// in different threads
void someFunction();
{
    // Can be called from many threads...
    MyLogger::sharedInstance().logMessage("some message");
}



I think Scott Meyers still applies well for Singletons since c++11 (maybe a dupe, but I am not that familiar with c++20 yet.

"...Also the main reason I cannot use static local variable is because it needs to be shared between DLL/SO boundaries...." why won't the "...static local..." work across DLL/SO boundaries?

OP is asking a specific question here: Is my usage of memory ordering correct here? Will it have the expected behavior?.  This is a valid question, with decent effort put into it, and IMO deserves an answer.

@Ðаn but the question is still specific to C++, how should I tag it? I'm not aware how other languages handle that stuff. But anyway, if you can ignore the DLL/SO stuff and just accept that I want to initialize the variable myself, then the question will become purely C++ related.

The only case where Meyers doesn't work with clang is that clang is in C++98 mode (which is default on MacOS). Initialization is not atomic in that case. The you need a C++98-compatible singleton... It also wouldn't work on MSVS 2010, need a critical section.

Also.. an interesting thought... singleton in a .dll is not strictly a singleton in all cases Because you can load library several times. Not sure about local static variable case, but dynamic initialization wiould allow new instances of singleton.  Even global variables in library have separate instances.Which I abused a few times in past. Afaik there are shared, local and possibly  thread-local

I think I saw something different. In your case several loggers are created which might be wrong because their crration would change state of output system. It used atomic counter. It might be even somewhere on SO. Under the hood of static initialization also lies an atomic state

@Swift-FridayPie The construction of the Logger is no-op in regards to output. The state of the output system will be changed/initialized when the first logMessage() function call is made.

@Ðаn I never said there is something wrong with it. I have a specific use case and gave a minimal code example in order to show what I'm trying to do and to ask if my memory ordering parameters around the atomic variable will work as I imagine they will, because sometimes I doubt my understanding of memory ordering(memory barriers) in the C++ language.

You cannot use std::memory_order_relaxed for this. Suppose thread A sees a non-null pointer to the logger. This means some thread B constructed a logger and made the pointer point to it. But the logger is constructed only from the thread B perspective. Thread A may see the memory occupied by the logger in a different and inconsistent state.

After tons of research and discussion and thanks to the answer of @user17732522 and the really good comments from @PeterCordes I finally understand the issues in the code from my question. There are two changes which have to be made. The load operation have to become std::memory_order_consume and the third parameter(success case) of compare_exchange_strong call should become std::memory_order_release.
I will try to explain as much as I can why and how things happens here, but first lets establish some base ground:

Compiler and or CPU cannot change the observable logic of the function in a single threaded perspective.
Atomic operations on an atomic variables are... well guaranteed to be atomic even in the relaxed memory ordering, you cannot have middle state on the variable there.

An example issue about the compare_exchange_strong in my question is that the compiler can reorder the object creation(as @user17732522 pointed out). So imagine the following theoretical scenario:

The memory for the MyLogger is allocated and the address is assigned to the local logger variable. However, the constructor still might not be called as the compiler and/or CPU can reorder that operation, because of the relaxed semantics and because the compare_exchange_strong only rely on the pointer address, not on its object state.
Another thread enters and reads the pointer address, while the constructor of MyLogger() is still not called or in progress, thus resulting in having valid memory address pointing to an object in an unknown state.
Usages after that are undefined behavior...

To the rescue comes std::memory_order_consume for the load operation and std::memory_order_release for the success case of the compare-exchange. The release semantics make it so no operations can be reordered after it, thus guaranteeing that both the local variable logger gets the memory address and the construction of the MyLogger instance is completed, thus when the pointer address is written to sSharedInstance by the compare_exchange_strong() call it is guaranteed that the object will be in a fully constructed state.
We can leave the failure case of compare_exchange_strong() to std::memory_order_relaxed, because it uses a local stack variable which of course can be seen only by a single thread.
Now, initially I thought that at least the load operation can be kept with relaxed memory ordering, but thanks to @PeterCordes now I understand that due to some specific CPUs(notably DEC Alpha), even though the constuctor have finished execution, before the assignment of the new address to sSharedInstance another thread might be able to see the new pointer address but still not observe the object values which were changed by the MyLogger() constuctor... This is why for the load operation at least consume semantics are needed.
NOTE: std::memory_order_consume is temporary discouraged by the standard due to its complicated nature. Most compilers automatically promote it to std::memory_order_acquire, but in order to have extra safety, it would be better to use std::memory_order_acquire in the code too. For more info. check out this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Consume_ordering

Release store / relaxed load is like a roll-your-own std::memory_order_consume on real hardware (other than DEC Alpha) but isn't guaranteed by ISO C++.  If you want to reason the way you're approaching it (instead of relying on things guaranteed by the C++ standard like happens-before), you need to be aware of branch prediction an speculative execution: loads after the if (logger) can read from (coherent) cache before the value of logger is actually ready.  An acquire load would prevent that.

What saves you here is that deref, *logger, has a data dependency on the value loaded which the compiler can't plausibly optimize away, because it can't guess what non-null address could have been loaded.  The CPU won't be able to do loads from the *logger object until the address is ready.  See also What does memory_order_consume really do? / Do dependent reads require a load-acquire? (another case of code that's technically unsafe in the same way as this answer.)

See also Paul McKenney's CPPCon talk about this stuff, including for the Linux kernel where they roll their own memory-order stuff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZrNQKpOypqU&index=44&list=PLHTh1InhhwT75gykhs7pqcR_uSiG601oh

@PeterCordes Thanks for the comments. In general, I'm ok with the first if (logger) loading a cached variable, because it will still either be a nullptr or a valid address to an object. However, as far as I understand, even a relaxed memory order is guaranteed to work on the atomic variable itself in terms of update visibility. For example you can have a std::atomic_int reference counter and increment it in a relaxed manner from many, many threads(lets say with fixed for loops) and in the end, once all the threads are finished you will always have the same result number.

Yes, you're guaranteed to see either nullptr or the address obtained by new.  But later loads dereferencing that pointer are not guaranteed to see stores to that object done by the constructor.  Caching has nothing to do with it.  You could be accessing a partially-constructed object (on DEC Alpha, or in a hypothetical C++ implementation that finds some other way to break your code because of the data-race UB without a happens-before.)

In practice this is safe because of the de-facto consume semantics on real hardware from the way you're using the load result (just by dereferencing the pointer, not also assuming that any other memory is also up-to-date from before the release store.)  But your answer needs to say that; I downvoted because you're incorrectly claiming that it's fully safe in ISO C++ in general.

@PeterCordes But basically the release semantics of the compare_exchange_strong will guarantee that the constructor is being fully called, before assigning the new address to the global variable. Or you are saying that, even if this is the case, still because of CPU cache some other thread might see the new pointer address, but not the new values which were assigned to the object members by the constructor, even though the constructor have finished execution? Is this really possible? Also could you comment the code which I've pasted from cppreference, which is basically doing the same magic?

Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.  The release in the writer makes sure that the pointed-to memory is ready before the pointer itself is visible to other threads, but the reader can potentially violate causality and read the pointed-to data before the actual address.  Most real CPUs could do this if it had been an if (data_ready.load(relaxed)) read(payload), but only DEC Alpha could violate causality and read the pointed-to memory before the pointer it just loaded: Dependent loads reordering in CPU

So in C++ this can normally only break when the compiler knows only one possible non-null address is possible and transforms if(ptr) *ptr into if (ptr) independent access of some fixed address.  A hypothetical CPU that does value-prediction for data loads could break this; C++ is intentionally weak enough to not assume data-dependency ordering; that's what consume was for.  See my earlier links.

In the cppreference code, the function returns void.  It's just publishing it to other threads.  The load is only to get an initial value for the CAS's expected arg and a tentative value for the new linked-list node we're about to publish.  We're not dereferencing the head.load() result; if we were, then we'd want at least consume (or acquire since consume is currently deprecated.)  The part of your code that requires consume or acquire is return *logger; (and an actual caller that uses the reference.)

@PeterCordes Many thanks for your patience and detailed explanation. I now understand the issues and edited my answer. Please check it out and if everything is good it would be really nice to put an upvote too. :)

Yup, looks good now.

No, it is not safe.
Relaxed memory ordering is not sufficient. You need acquire-release ordering. Otherwise you are establishing a happens-before relationship only on the pointer value itself, not on the object that the pointer points to or its subobjects or other objects that the constructor accesses.
Also, in contrast to the behavior of local dynamic initialization, you will not have any guarantee that multiple constructions won't be attempted in parallel. That may be fine, but is a problem e.g. if the constructor accesses global state.

@TheStorm If the constructor is a noop then there is no reason to not just write constinit inline static MyLogger sSharedInstance; at class scope and use that variable directly. With your implementation, formally, it doesn't make a difference though. There would still be a race on the lifetime of the object and therefore UB without acquire/release.

In terms of no-op I meant that a global shared state it not touched. The constructor will initialize member variables of the class, which are not constexpr, but they don't do anything specific in terms of operation.

It doesn't matter what the contents of the the atomic is or how the object is initialized, you cannot use relaxed for the reasons stated in the answer. Suppose you have instead a std::atomic<bool> instead of atomic<T*>, and your initialization race initializes an object static T sSharedInstance; - clearly with relaxed order, reading a value of true says absolutely nothing about the state of sSharedInstance (this being the very definition of relaxed order).

@TheStorm If the constructor initializes a data member, then that's not a no-op (aka trivial) constructor and then relaxed ordering is definitively, also in practice, wrong. The member is a shared state between the two threads. With relaxed ordering there is no guarantee that the other thread will actually see the member initialized when it reads the pointer from the atomic. The compiler is permitted to e.g. reorder writing the member to after the relaxed compare_exchange of the pointer.

Specifically, the correct parameters should be sSharedInstance.load(std::memory_order_acquire); and sSharedInstance.compare_exchange_strong(previousLogger, logger, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_acquire)

@user2407038 But I don't have two variables which I need to synchronize, I have only one. The compiler can't reorder stuff here, because it will change the logic even in single threaded case. As you probably know, compiler optimize stuff having only a single threaded perspective, but I have atomic operations here, so they can't be optimized out. They can be only reordered, but only in a way which will not change the logic in a single threaded case.

@user17732522 Well, the related member variables also have no-op constructors, but they are not constexpr, because they have complex destructors. Things like std::string for example. I still count it as no-op.

@TheStorm This has little to do with the compiler reordering operations. Even if it does not do any reordering (and it likely doesn't), the generated code, which when executed by a multicore processor, may result in different effects being visible in different orders on different threads. relaxed order means that any effects occurring on the thread which performs the relaxed store, may visible in an arbitrary order on other threads. "effects" here includes writing to memory, regardless of whether you "count it as a no-op"

@user2407038 As I mentioned, redundant objects are not a problem as they will be deleted immediately by the if check. The other variables are local to the function. The only variable which is going to be seen by multiple threads is sSharedInstance on which I have compare_exchange_strong which either fails or succeeds. There is no middle ground here. Two threads cannot simultaneously overwrite it. This is why is called atomic. You can very well try increasing an atomic_int on multiple threads with relaxed semantics. In the end you will always have the same number, no count will be skipped.

@TheStorm I'm afraid you've misunderstood something core about atomics, or about memory order guarantees. There is no question about the use of compare_exchange_strong, but that has no impact with regards to the previous load. Immediately after sSharedInstance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed), if you have found a non-null pointer there, the fact that you are using relaxed means that the effects which have written to memory pointed-to by that pointer may not be visible - so dereferencing the pointer is a formally a data race.

@user2407038 But if I find a non-null pointer during the first if check, this means that compare_exchange_strong have passed and the pointer will be valid, because the initial value is nullptr so I can't have some random garbage address and the dereference will be valid. On the other hand, if I find nullptr during the first if then it will come to compare_exchange_strong where it will pass once and fail for everyone else, no matter how many threads have passed the first if check.

@TheStorm The pointer will be valid and point to the new object, but that doesn't imply anything about whether or not the initialization of that object will be visible to the other thread. The whole reason that different memory ordering exists is that apriori there is no guarantee that one thread will observe all memory access in the same order as any other thread. And relaxed ordering doesn't change anything about that.

@TheStorm Suppose MyLogger was struct MyLogger { bool a = true; void logMessage(const char*) { if(a) doSomething();  };. Then, when the compare_exchange_strong succeeds in thread 1 and thread 2 loads the instance in someFunction, then with relaxed ordering there is no guarantee that the call to logMessage will see a initialized. It could read a garbage value for it from before initialization and the value may tear. It is UB for a data race or a race on the lifetime of the object.

@TheStorm The compiler is for example allowed to reorder the initialization of the object after the compare_exchange_strong with relaxed ordering (as is the CPU as well). But that's just one implementation detail. You should be programming against the C++ memory model specification, not against specific compiler optimizations or CPU memory models.

@user17732522 So, if I understand correctly, you say that the compiler can allocate the memory for the local variable logger = new MyLogger();, assign the address to it, pass the compare_exchange_strong operation and then call the constructor to initialize it?

@user17732522 Tbh I find that hard to believe as the compiler cannot change the logic of the function in a single threaded context, but even if that's the case, later I have delete for any redundant object and that redundant object is local to the function, so it can be seen only by a single thread and so the constructor must have finished, before the delete call. Also when I'm doing the return of the dereferenced object, no matter the ordering, all the function operations must be completed. The compiler cannot reorder the construction after the function returns.

"and then call the constructor to initialize it?": Yes, or interleave it arbitrarily, or see that delete means that the member is never used before it is destructed and therefore skip initialization in that branch or anything else. There is no reason to believe that there must be a single unique constructor call in the machine instructions generated to implement your function.

"Tbh I find that hard to believe as the compiler cannot change the logic of the function in a single threaded context,": Nothing is changing the logic in a single thread. All of the transformations I mentioned wouldn't affect the behavior of the single-threaded program at all. "later I have delete for any redundant object and that redundant object is local to the function, so it can be seen only by a single thread and so the constructor must have finished, before the delete call.": In the example I gave you there is only one attempt to construct the object which is not deleted.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"Also when I'm doing the return of the dereferenced object, no matter the ordering, all the function operations must be completed." Only to the extent that their completion would affect behavior in the same thread, not in other threads, because threads do not need to agree on the order or timing in which object modifications become visible, except where memory ordering guarantees provide for it.

@user17732522 As per our private chat you've managed to convince me, but before accepting your answer I would like you to edit it with some theoretical examples of what might happen(given the constructor is not accessing global state).

@user17732522 But also having a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange and the example code there, I still have seconds thoughts at least for the relaxed load() operation(that I can leave it relaxed).
